# Desktop configuration file does something different from just running the Exec command

Tags: sound, wine, .desktop

I installed the game Gothic on my Ubuntu 18.04 today, using wine. The final problem that needed a fix was the background music, solved by running `winetricks directmusic`. Now I can navigate to the directory with the executable (`/home/[user name]/.wine32/drive_c/GOG Games/Gothic/system`), and run `wine GOTHIC.EXE`, and everything is fine.

As part of the installation, wine put a `.desktop` file on my desktop. It didn't do anything useful, so I appropriated it to run Gothic. It now looks like this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Gothic
Exec=wine '/home/[user name]/.wine32/drive_c/GOG Games/Gothic/system/GOTHIC.EXE'
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Path=/home/[user name]/
Icon=2BDB_goggame-1207658682.0
StartupWMClass=gothic.exe
```

However, when I double click it, Gothic runs without music. Running `wine '/home/[user name]/.wine32/drive_c/GOG Games/Gothic/system/GOTHIC.EXE'` in a terminal launches Gothic with music.

How can the two be different? What steps can I take to rectify this and be able to use the `.desktop` file as a handy shortcut?

---

**Edit:** I have now, just to add a layer of indirection, tried making a simple shell script to run the `wine` command, and launched that through both the terminal and through the `.desktop` file. The problem still persists: Terminal launch means music, `.desktop` launch means no music.

Comment: Please try changing the `Exec`  line to `Exec=bash -c 'wine '/home/[user name]/.wine32/drive_c/GOG Games/Gothic/system/GOTHIC.EXE''` and report back.

Comment: @pomsky Then it didn't do anything. However, `Exec=bash -c 'wine /home/arthur/.wine32/drive_c/GOG\ Games/Gothic/system/GOTHIC.EXE'` (with the escaped space rather than quote-within-quote) did exactly the same as before: launched the game, no music.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `Path`, `StartupNotify` and `StartupWMClass` entries?

Comment: @pomsky I notice that if I had been just a little bit more familiar with the concept of `.desktop` files, I might have thought to check these myself first, rather than have you explicitly go through what is basically "have you tried turning it off and on again?". I appreciate the patience. But to answer your question, no, this didn't change a thing. The `.desktop` file still can't launch the program properly. (I did also just try rebooting, just because I thought about it. Didn't work.)

Comment: It's alright :) I'm repeatedly coming up with various suggestions as I'm also intrigued by this issue, otherwise I wouldn't have engaged in the first place. Sorry it didn't work out. Hopefully someone else would come up with a solution. In a related note, if you wish to learn more about `.desktop` launchers, you may check these out: https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html and https://developer.gnome.org/desktop-entry-spec/